# How to config Single node for Single Cluster (Standalone Cluster) ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I installed elastic search in my local machine, I want to configure it as the only one single node in the cluster(Standalone Server). it means whenever I create a new index, it will only available to my server. It will not be accessible to other's server.

My current scenario these indexes are available to other servers (the servers are formed in a cluster), and they can make any changes to my indexes. But I don't want it.

I went through some other blogs but not getting best solution. So can you please let me know steps for same?

Comment: Alternatively you can change the cluster name of your server.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I ve got the answer from http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/How-to-isolate-elastic-search-node-from-other-nodes-td3977389.html.

Kimchy : You set the node to local(true), this means it will not discover other nodes using network, only within the same JVM.

in elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch.yml file

```
node.local: true # disable network
```

### Updated for ES 7.x

in elasticsearch.yml

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.type: single-node
```

and make sure you have **cluster.initial_master_nodes** off

```
# cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
```

credited to @Chandan.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere in the official reference?

Comment: it is not documented, like a half of elasticsearch "features"

Comment: `node.local` has been deprecated. See @felix-borzik answer below.

Comment: See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263329/368683) for ElasticSearch 5.0 and later.

Comment: My version 6 installation does not recognize `node.local` at all.

Answer (score 26):

In `elasticsearch.yml`

```
# Note, that for development on a local machine, with small indices, it usually
# makes sense to "disable" the distributed features:
#
index.number_of_shards: 1
index.number_of_replicas: 0
```

Use the same configuration in your code.

Also to isolate the node use `node.local: true` or `discovery.zen.ping.multicast: false`

Comment: See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263329/368683) for ElasticSearch 5.0 and later.

Comment: This fails in v6 and probably later. "index" settings must not be in the general settings file.

Answer (score 23):

Here's relevant info for ElasticSearch 5:

According to [changelog](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_settings_changes.html#_node_settings), to enable local mode on ES 5 you need to add `transport.type: local` to your `elasticsearch.yml` instead of `node.local: true`.

Comment: This response worked for me. Note that some of the older answers may be outdated.  

Here is a working link  to the above mentioned [changelog](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_settings_changes.html#_node_settings)

Comment: `local` state has been removed from ES 6.0.x [commit](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/8a20dae6207e927576287c1742592d3e1b932065)

Answer (score 23):

If you intend to run Elasticseach on a Single Node and be able to bind it to public IP, two important settings are:

```
network.host: <PRIVATE IP OF HOST>
discovery.type: single-node
```

Comment: This works on 7.x; thanks. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/bootstrap-checks.html

Answer (score 14):

If you're using a network transport in your code, this won't work, as `node.local` gives you a LocalTransport only:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html#_local_transport

The trick then is to set

`discovery.zen.ping.multicast: false`

in your `elasticsearch.yml` which will stop your node looking for any other nodes.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#multicast

I'm not sure if this prevents other nodes from discovering yours though; I only needed this to affect a group of nodes with the same settings on the same network.

Comment: See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263329/368683) for ElasticSearch 5.0 and later.

Answer (score 12):

I wanted to do this without having to write/overwrite an elasticsearch.yml in my container. Here it is without a config file

Set an environment variable prior to starting elasticsearch:

`discovery.type=single-node`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer. It is the documented solution to this problem from Elasticsearch docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html#single-node-discovery

Answer (score 5):

In the *config* file, add:

- `network.host: 0.0.0.0` [in Network settings]
- `discovery.type: single-node` [in Discovery and Cluster formation settings]

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer. It is the documented solution to this problem from Elasticsearch docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html#single-node-discovery

Answer (score 3):

This solve your problem:

```
PUT /_all/_settings
{"index.number_of_replicas":0}
```

Tested with ES version 5.

Answer (score 1):

All of these didn´t help me (and I sadly didn´t read the answer of bhdrkn). The thing that worked for me was to change elasticsearch´s cluster-name everytime I need to have a separate instance, where new nodes aren´t added automatically via multicast.

Just change cluster.name: {{ elasticsearch.clustername }} in elasticsearch.yml, e.g. via Ansible. This is particulary helpful, when building separate Stages like Dev, QA and Production (which is a standard usecase in enterprise-environments).

And if you´re using logstash to get your data into elasticsearch, don´t forget to put the same cluster-name into the output-section, like:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        cluster => "{{ elasticsearch.clustername }}"
    }
}
```

Otherwise your "logstash-*"-index will not be build correctly...