# Settings to improve elasticsearch startup time for unit tests?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm writing tests that start a elasticsearch 6.4 single-node cluster to ensure that my queries behave as expected. It takes about 10 seconds for the cluster to start an my tests RestHighLevelClient to ping it without a connection error

```java
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("elasticsearch").start();
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(
  new HttpHost('localhost', 9200, 'http'),
  new HttpHost('localhost', 9201, 'http'),

));

// wait for cluster, takes about 10 seconds in practice.
do {
  try {
    client.ping(RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    break;
  } catch (IOException ex) { }
} while (true);
```

Are there settings I can change to improve startup time?

- I don't need to persist indexes across test runs, so the index could be kept in memory. I don't see `memory` listed in the [6.4 store types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/index-modules-store.html)
- Are there settings that cause the whole cluster to run without writing to disk (disable logging, disable file storage, disable pid/state)?
- The cluster will be single-node so I can disable discovery, but I haven't found that setting. Edit: `discovery.type=single-node` in 6.4

Comment: I found some good answers for various versions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432300/how-to-config-single-node-for-single-cluster-standalone-cluster-elasticsearch). `discovery.type=single-node` shaves off 4 seconds.

Comment: I suspect a lot of this is due to a sprawling code base/feature set and JVM slowness and operating only with Hotspot, not e.g. Graal. It is really unfortunate. PostgreSQL takes 1s to start for tests. Elasticsearch takes 8s.

Comment: @PaulDraper what version are you running? Also here is an [interesting investigation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28650) of startup times during test cases.

Comment: @Val thanks I will read that.

Answer (score 7):

There's no way so store all indexes into memory. `index.store.type: memory` did exist in ES 1.x but [disappeared in ES 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_setting_changes.html#_in_memory_indices) a long time ago.

You can [disable all logging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logging.html) by modifying te `log4j2.properties` file and setting all loggers to OFF (and optionally use a NullAppender)

```
logger.action.level = OFF
rootLogger.level = OFF
logger.deprecation.level = OFF
logger.index_search_slowlog_rolling.level = OFF
logger.index_indexing_slowlog.level = OFF
logger.xpack_security_audit_logfile.level = OFF
```

Regarding disabling the discovery, you got it right by setting `discovery.type=single-node`